# Trying to choose a search engine

Tags: search, low-search, supersearch

I'm building a new site that will contain alot of news items and archived pdf publications. I'm wondering if anyone with experience using Solspace Super Search, Low Search, and Google Search would be willing to share their thoughts on the pros/cons and differences between these three options.

Basically, I would like a search engine that is a little more robust than the native EE option and Super Search and Low seem like they will do the trick. However, one question I have about using Google Search is the time it takes for Google to index the pages on my site. I'm assuming it may not be immediate. This would be important because the site will be new.

Any insight will be appreciated.

Comment: I haven't use Low Search but used Super Search a lot and I love it. Very powerful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure any of the options you mentioned other than Google will actually index the content of PDFs. You may have to create an entry for each one with the text content. Maybe there's an add-on that will grab the text out for you (I know it's possible).

I've used Low Search and Super Search. Both are excellent but I'd probably go with Low.

Comment: Thanks, foamcow. Yes, each PDF entry will have a description and list authors so I think I'd be able to live without indexing the content inside the PDF.

Answer (score 4):

I'm using Low Search, it's really more powerful than the native EE search, very well documented, nice user interface. You can parameter the weight of each field, categories of the each collection of search. Easy to integrate in a project.

You can parameter complex search. And the Low support is very good and efficient.

Comment: Thanks, Stéphane. With Low's reputation I think this is the direction I'm leaning towards.

Comment: Yes, Low is very professional and always he gives a great support.